# Добавление связи один к одному

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2

Добавил связь один к одному:

```
oneToOne:
    acceptedUser:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\User
        joinColumn:
            name: accepted_by_user_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Внешние ключи добавились, но теперь `accepted_by_user_id` `UNIQUE` на уровне базы.

Как убрать уникальность, и почему она вообще добавилась?

Answer (score 1):

OneToOne подразумевает, что одна сущность может быть связана только с одной другой сущностью, т.е., если одна связь в БД есть, то второй такой быть не может, оттуда и уникальность. Судя по тому, что она вам мешает, у вас связь не один к одному, а многие к одному / один ко многим.